# how to copy and overwrite file in command prompt even if the file is being use by another program

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, command-prompt, xcopy

Hi all,

I want copy file from one location to another in **command prompt** using **XCOPY** method of copying files in windows.

It actually works fine, but the problem is whenever the file is used by another program is cannot be overwritten rather leave the files in the destination as it is.

Here are the command i used.

```
 if not exist "%systemdrive%\Program Files (x86)" 
    (  
       if not exist "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data\indigenedb" 
         ( 
           No Database to be restored 
         ) 
       else 
         ( 
           XCOPY "C:\Users\Engr\Desktop\hahahahah" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data\indigenedb" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /F 
         )  
     ) 
 else 
     (  
       if not exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data\indigenedb" 
         ( 
            No Database to be restored ) else ( XCOPY "C:\Users\Engr\Desktop\hahahahah" "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\data\indigenedb" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /F  
         ) 
     )
```

The command would check if the system is not **32-Bit** Processor then the operation is going to be in **C:\Program Files (x86)** instead of **C:\Program Files**. and if the it is **32-Bit**  not **64-Bit** then it would perform the operation in **C:\Program Files**.

Thank you.

Comment: If the file is in use, then it cannot be overwritten. That is why even Windows Update has to reboot the system in order to write over files that were in use at the time of update.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: @Liturgist Alright, i now understand. Thank you.